# Django - media files not being shown on website

Tags: django, media

I've got a problem with user uploaded content not showing up on webpages. I have this working 100% on using my development settings.py file, but this doesn't work on my live site.

A couple of notes

1. My static files are working 100% on my live site.
2. When a user uploads content on my live site, the file posts to the correct folder (i.e. the folder that I've specified in my settings.py file)
3. When the webpage is rendered, and the broken link is investigated, to me, it looks like the link is correct. In other words, the image exists at the link indicated.

Here are my media settings in settings.py:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/jasonhoward/webapps/site_media/'
```

If a user uploads cat.jpg, I've confirmed that it successfully saves to '/home/jasonhoward/webapps/site_media/'

Now, when the user navigates to the image gallery on their profile, what should appear is the image of the cat. Instead, a broken link appears. The address of the image is '/media/cat.jpg' as per Chrome Inspect tool.

To me, the link address seems correct and the image should be displayed. It's almost like the file path is correct, but the system is restricting access to this image for some reason. Is that possible?

The only other thing that I can think of is that in the main urls.py file, I've got the following code:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Debug mode is set to False in production. I've tried removing the 'if settings.DEBUG' line, but this doesn't change any behavior.

I should mention that my static files are setup like this:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/' 
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/jasonhoward/webapps/site_static/' 
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets', 'our_static'),)
```

When I got to www.mysite.com/static/images/car.jpg, the car image loads in the browser. As a result, I'm confused as to why the media files don't work...

Thanks

Comment: Presumably you have something configured in production to serve the static files. You need to do the same with your media files.

Comment: My understanding is that media files should be uploaded to and served to webpages from '/home/jasonhoward/webapps/site_media/' as a result of MEDIA_ROOT declaration in the settings.py file. The one declaration seems to work for in my dev environment.

Comment: Uploaded to there, yes. But what is serving them? As I said, in order to get static files working you must have configured your web server to serve them. You need to do that for the media files too.

Comment: @JasonHoward It works in your dev environment because of the `urlpatterns` you have `if settings.DEBUG`. You don't give the details of your production environment, but you have to configure it to serve the files in `/home/jasonhoward/webapps/site_media/` at `/media`.

Comment: @Paulo Almeida Why do the regular static files work and not the media files in production if its that "if settings.Debug" is causing the issue?

Comment: @JasonHoward `if settings.DEBUG` is not causing the issue, it is serving the media and static folders in your development environment. In production you need to configure whatever mechanism is serving static to also serve media.

Comment: @Paulo Almeida The mechanism that is serving static files is this: STATIC_URL = '/static/' 
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/jasonhoward/webapps/site_static/' I've setup media variants of this in the exact same format as per above.

Comment: No. If static files are working in production it's because *you have configured something to serve them*. They don't work by magic, and Django doesn't serve them. You did something. Do that for media too.

Comment: @JasonHoward You are describing the Django part, which does seem fine (files are uploaded to `MEDIA_ROOT` and links are created with `/media/`). What we are telling you is that there must be _something_ on the server receiving requests for the path `/media`, presumably on port 80, and mapping them to your `MEDIA_ROOT`. If static is working, that mechanism is correctly configured for that case. You didn't say how things are being served, it varies a lot. It could be an Apache `<Location>`, configuration in a panel on a web host or PaaS, etc...

Comment: I can't see how static is being served in a way that media is not. I'm convinced that django doesn't allow for the serving of media files anymore. I've hooked up with amazon s3 and I'm now able to sever media and static files.

Comment: @JasonHoward That's right, Django doesn't serve media files, but it also doesn't serve static, if DEBUG is False, so there really must be something doing it. You never described your previous setup, so it's impossible to know what. Anyway, it's working now on S3, so it's all good.

Comment: @PauloAlmeida Ya, I guess I'm kind of confused. It is working now, so I do thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't rely on serving static or media files through Django. Instead, you should configure your http server (nginx, apache, lighttpd etc) to serve them directly.

Comment: That's fair. I do plan on moving to Amazon S3, but the fact that I'm serving media files and static files from my webhost shouldn't cause this issue, right?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add the `static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)` in the `urls.py` file in the main django-app